# php doesn't redirect correctly

Tags: php, html, apache2, raspberry-pi

I'm running a apache2 server on my raspberry pi that's hosting my website.
By clicking on a link on my website i'm able to change some values in a textfile.

Now everything works just fine but when the link in my script redirects to the homepage, there seems to be something going wrong.

After redirecting the url isn't *192.168.1.101/index.php*, instead it stays *192.168.1.101/scripts/beheerSOD.php?sproeier=1*

If I refresh the page the url changes to *192.168.1.101/index.php* but the script also executes again

Does someone know what's going on?

Thank you in advance!

**HTML link to script (index.php)**

```
<a href="scripts/beheerSOD.php?sproeier=1">Klik op mij!</a>
```

**Script that redirects in the end (scripts/beheerSOD.php)**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['sproeier'])){

    $sproeier = $_GET['sproeier'];
    $SODtxt = file_get_contents('../SOD.txt');
    $sproeierIO = $SODtxt{($sproeier-1)};
    if($sproeierIO=="0"){
        $sproeierIO="1";
    }
    else{
        $sproeierIO="0";
    }
    $eerst = substr($SODtxt,0,$sproeier-1);
    $laatst = substr($SODtxt,$sproeier,strlen($SODtxt));
    $SODtxt = $eerst.$sproeierIO.$laatst;
    file_put_contents('../SOD.txt', $SODtxt);
    header("Location: http://192.168.1.101/index.php");
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the header statement at the top of your script.

Comment: this doesn't change anything, the url is still incorrect after the redirect

Comment: even if I change it to _header("Location: http://192.168.1.101/index.php?test=1");_ it still redirects me to _192.168.1.101/scripts/beheerSOD.php?sproeier=1_ . after i refresh it's _http://192.168.1.101/index.php?test=1_ I have no clue what's going on